# Google Site Search - 10 Result Limitation

Tags: javascript, search

We are implementing a Google Site Search for a client, and need access to all of the results for custom result output.

Currently only 10 results are returned at a time, is there a way to retrieve more than 10, preferably the entire result set.

Answer (score 0):

Are you scraping the web site? If so, turn off Google Instant because that option limits you to 10 search results. In your search settings, you will be able to set the number of returned results. Obviously, you can't return the *entire* result set, though.